# Is faster code also more power efficient?

Tags: optimization, language-agnostic, cpu

Assume I have a CPU running at a constant rate, pulling an equal amount of energy per instruction. I also have two functionally identical programs, which result in the same output, except one has been optimized to execute only 100 instructions, while the other program executes 200 instructions. Is the 100 instruction program necessarily faster than the 200 instruction program? Does a program with fewer instructions draw less power than a program with more instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things are much more complex than this.

For example execution speed is in many cases dominated by memory. As a practical example some code could process the pixels of an image first in rows and then in columns... a different code instead could be more complex but processing rows and columns at the same time.

The second version could execute more instructions because of more complex housekeeping of the data but I wouldn't be surprised if it was faster because of how memory is organized: reading an image one column at a time is going to "trash the cache" and it's very possible that despite being simple the code working that way could be a LOT slower than the more complex one doing the processing in a memory-friendly way. The simpler code may end up being "stalled" a lot waiting for the cache lines to be filled or flushed to the external memory.

This is just an example, but in reality what happens inside a CPU when code is executed is for many powerful processors today a very very complex process: instructions are exploded in micro-instructions, registers are renamed, there is speculative execution of parts of code depending on what branch predictors guess even before the program counter really reaches a certain instruction and so on. Today the only way to know for sure if something is faster or slower is in many cases just trying with real data and measure.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the 100 instruction program necessarily faster than the 200 instruction program?

No. Firstly, on some architectures ([such as x86](https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf)) different instructions can take a different number of cycles. Secondly, there are effects — such cache misses, page faults and branch mispreditictions — that complicate the picture further.

From this it follows that the answer to your headline question is "not necessarily".

[Further reading](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/cooldc16/cooldc16-paper-hirki.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I found a [paper from 2017](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3136014.3136031) comparing the energy usage, speed, and memory consumption of various programming languages. There is an obvious positive correlation between faster languages also using less energy.

[image: Table showing results from the paper]